# Cant find a description getsourcecode response

Tags: proxy-contracts, api

I'm currently writing a script that scans the source code of smart contracts to filter out different information. Im mainly doing this with the getsourcecode action from the API.

In addition to retrieving the source code, this also sends other data, the ABI, the ContractName, etc.
Some of these are self-explanatory to me, but with some I dont exactly know what they tell me, and I was not able to find an explanation for them anywhere.

I'm particularly interested in the one called "Proxy".

If anyone could point me to some place where these are explained more thoroughly, I'd be very thankful.

EDIT:

Basically I'm searching for a description of all the parts of "Results" which you get from get the getsourcecode action
(see "Response" under https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts#get-contract-source-code-for-verified-contract-source-codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand Proxies, you should first learn about a solidity's low level instruction - **delegatecall**, which essentially allows you to execute other contracts functions in context of your own contract.

For instance you have 2 contracts:

```
contract contractA {

    uint a = 0;
    uint b = 1;

    function caller(address adr) public {
        address(adr).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("addNumbers"));
    }
}


contract contractB {
    
    uint256 a=2;
    uint256 b=3;
    
    function addNumbers() public returns (uint256) {
        a = b;
    }
}
```

Delegatecall in this case would work in such a way, that when in caller method you provide contractB's address, it will execute the addNumbers method, but instead of using contractB's a and b it will use contractA's. The result of this call would be that contractA's a will become 3 and contractB's storage variables remain the same.

Now this is important because Proxy is nothing else than contractA, that only has 1 function, which then calls different functions in contractB. This is a nice feature, because it lets you change adr in contract A and just call another contract's function, which is basically making a contract **upgradable**.

To read more about it visit: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy

Comment: Thanks but I already know about delegatecall, I also know what a proxy contract is. 
What I dont know is, when I use getsourcecode and receive the source code and some extra data, e.g.:
         "CompilerVersion":"v0.3.1-2016-04-12-3ad5e82",
         "OptimizationUsed":"1",
         "Runs":"200",
         "EVMVersion":"Default",
         "Library":"",
         "LicenseType":"",
         "Proxy":"0",
         "Implementation":"",
         "SwarmSource":""
Exactly what all of this extra data is telling me, especially e.g. "Proxy : 0"

Comment: I did some tests and it turns out that if a contract is a proxy it will return 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: Thats what I thought thanks! Would you say that that makes it very likely the contract was designed to be upgradable or are there other reasons it would be a proxy?

Comment: Well you can check out the diamond standard ERC-2535 which implements a proxy but in order to modularize contract and etherscan classified this as a proxy as well.